# Template Settings on M2E pro 6.x.x on Magento 1.8

Tags: php, magento, m2e

I have installed M2E 6.x.x extension on Magento 1.8 for eBay store sync. It has created a menu "Sell on eBay" within the Admin Panel. Now I could not find a way to change the template settings.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings for the listing templates are held in:

**Sell on eBay > Configuration > Policies Tab > Description Policy**

**Note:** You will only see this in the top menu after you have been through the M2E Pro setup wizard which creates the policies for you and put at least one item into a listing group.

Once setup, open the description policy, scroll down to the description section, set the product description to be a custom description and you can add & edit the description template layout.

You'll find these video guides helpful http://understandinge.com/magento-tutorial/ebay-listing-templates/ which cover M2EPro listing templates.

Also if you wanted to use a jQuery lightbox in the listing template for the media gallery keyword then see this article http://understandinge.com/ebay-listing-template-image-lightbox/

Hope that helps you,

Matt